# \cpageref from cleveref produces wrong label

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The code that follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalize, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  %
  \caption{Sample.}
  \label{fig:sample}
  %
  \centering
  %
  Some nice picture goes here.
  %
\end{figure}

Some text referring to the stuff on \cpageref{fig:sample}.

\end{document}
```

Produces the result:

[image]

Is this a bug in the `cleveref` package or am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Yes, this is apparently a bug introduced in the latest version. The version from 2013 works as expected

Comment: For now, I just re-defined the command:
`\def\cpageref{\myownpagecommand}`

Does this seem like a reasonable solution? My goal is to be able to remove that line when the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in `cleveref 0.21.1` from 2018/02/08. The version 0.19 from 2013 works as expected.

A small workaround extracts the hyper anchor with `refcount` features (loaded by `hyperref` anyway).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalize, noabbrev]{cleveref}



\renewcommand{\cpageref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{}{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{??}}{Page \getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[!htbp]
  %
  \caption{Sample.} \label{fig:sample}
  %
  \centering
  %
  Some nice picture goes here.
  %
\end{figure}

Some text referring to the stuff on \cpageref{fig:sample}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\newcommand*{\mypageref}[1]{page~\pageref{#1}}` followed by `\def\cpageref{\mypageref}`?

Comment: @dow: Also possible... but in general, you should use `\renewcommand` etc.... -- your solution would not put the `Page` in the link, however, which was an option you used with `nameinlink`

Answer (score 6):

Fixed in the latest pre-release (currently v0.21.3), available from [my web site](http://www.dr-qubit.org/cleveref.html).

Please note that Stackexchange is not a bug tracker. Post questions to SE; report bugs via the software's normal bug-reporting channel. (Plain old email to the address given in the package docs for `cleveref`; bugzilla/github/trac/whatever-bug-tracker-it-uses for more sophisticated software.)

Bug reports are as valuable a part of free software development as code contributions. By all means ask about it on SE first, but don't forget to submit a proper bug report too! Otherwise they risk languishing on SE unnoticed, unloved and unfixed.

Comment: Thanks for fixing! By the way, did you change the way how the arguments in in your `\newlabel{foo@cref}{....}` macros are stored?

Comment: You are right, I should not have omitted submitting a bug report after confirming on SE. Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, the '\newlabel's now store additional page reference data. The '\newlabel' format is an internal implementation detail, and has changed from time to time. However, the '\cref@getlabel', '\cref@getprefix' etc. (and now '\cpageref@getlabel' etc.) accessor macros for extracting this data have been there almost since v0.1, and get updated when the format changes. I'm not going to make any promises about maintaining full backwards compatibility forever, but if you need to access the cleveref data those accessor macros are probably the safest bet.

Comment: @TobyCubitt: Thank you for the information. If I have known about `\cref@getlabel` etc. I would not have written `crossreftools` as a separate package, most likely. May I suggest to mention those macros in the manual?

Comment: @MdAyquassar Apologies, it should have read version 0.21.3, which was the latest version when I posted that answer. Since then I've released version 0.21.4, which is also available on CTAN now.